# How to apply multithreading on tkinter in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

Hi I've learning tkinter on python3 and I'm trying to use multithreading on tkinter to open a few windows also base on tkinter, but it seems that it can only open the first window and the second appears only after closing the first window. I use multithreading is to avoid a followed window being blocked by the previous, but it still seems happened. Here's part of my code and I replace the if statements with if something happened:
from tkinter import *# GUI window

```
import os
import _thread

top = Tk()
top.title("Test")

def pressbutton(count):
    if count <= 10:
        print(count)
        count += 1
        if count < 10:
            _thread.start_new_thread(pressbutton,(count,))
        if something happened:
            os.system("python t1.py")
        if something happened:
            os.system("python t2.py")

startButton =Button(top, text="Start", command=lambda: pressbutton(0))
startButton.grid(column=0, row=1)
```

t1.py and t2.py are two python files that also build with tkinter. What I'm trying to get is to have several t1 and t2 windows, but only one appears.

Comment: I don't think threads are the right way to go about opening multiple windows. Tkinter doesn't work nicely with multi-threading – at least, that was my experience in Python 2.7. Nonetheless, you should only have one `Tk()` open at any time. Then, you can create additional windows using `Toplevel()`.

Comment: If all you're doing is creating multiple windows, you definitely don't need threads. Just create instances of `Toplevel`.